# Homebrew gives me errors

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I'm having issues compiling something.  When I run brew doctor I get the following output.

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /opt/local/bin/curl-config
    /opt/local/bin/icu-config
    /opt/local/bin/libpng-config
    /opt/local/bin/libpng16-config
    /opt/local/bin/ncurses5-config
    /opt/local/bin/ncursesw5-config
    /opt/local/bin/pcre-config
    /opt/local/bin/pkg-config
    /opt/local/bin/python2.7-config

Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:
  /opt/local/bin/port

This can cause trouble. You don't have to uninstall them, but you may want to
temporarily move them out of the way, e.g.

  sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports

Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
  /opt/local/bin/pkg-config

`./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
this other pkg-config.
```

This is my /etc/paths file

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
```

I am confused why this is happening, I have removed everything and installed again from fresh, but I still get the same errors.

Comment: Do you have MacPorts installed?

Comment: Yes I do.  The latest version

Comment: Did you try moving it?

Comment: Those aren't errors they are warnings... They might possibly have no effect on why you can't install something.